# Experience manager temporary files

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

How can I configure (root) folder where XPM temporary files are created during page editing (when CP's are added/removed/reordered)?

I thought XPM was using cd_storage_conf.xml, but it is placing temporary files in a different folder then the one defined in the storage configuration.

Answer (score 3):

The temporary files are placed in the same locaton as the original page is, there is no option to move these to a separate location.

Comment: Hi Bart, in my case they are actuality placed at a different location then the original files. Temporary files are treating http upload website folder as webroot instead of the folder configured in the cd_storage

Comment: @user3760419 then it sounds like you have a bit of a mess in your configuration files, maybe your web application is using a different `cd_storage_conf.xml` than you expect, you can check that (in the logfile) when setting logging in debug mode and restarting your webapp. Please also note the documentation for which locations should be in what `cd_storage_conf.xml` (you typically have 3, the one from your website/webapp, the one from the cd upload and the one from the XPM odata)

Comment: Hi Bart, all cd_storage configuration files have the same mappings (same folder) for pages. Is there some other configuration item that can influence this behavior ?